# How can I override a virtual function with template argument in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, virtual-functions

How can I override a virtual function with template argument?
`virtual T accept(Visitor<T>);`

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Visitor{
public:
    template<typename K>
    T visit(K);
};

template<typename T>
class Expr{
public:
    virtual T accept(Visitor<T>);
};

template<typename T>
class Lit: public Expr<T>{
public:
    int value;
    Lit(int a){
        value = a;
    }
    T accept(Visitor<T> v) override{
        v.visit(*this);
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Add: public Expr<T>{
public:
    Expr<T> left, right;
    Add(Expr<T> a, Expr<T> b){
        left = a; right = b;
    }
    T accept(Visitor<T> v) override{
        v.visit(*this);
    }
};

class tv: public Visitor<int>{
public:

    int visit(Lit<int> a){
        return a.value;
    }
    int visit(Add<int> a){
        return a.left.accept(*this) + a.right.accept(*this);
    }
};

int main() {
    Add<int> a(Lit<int>(1), Lit<int>(2));
    tv testvisitor;
    std::cout << a.accept(testvisitor);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you have with the code you show? Please [edit] your question to tell us. Also please take some time to read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Not sure why you're calling out the `virtual T accept(Visitor<T>);`. That part is working just fine, because `T` is fixed by that point. The real problem is with Visitor's `template<typename K> T visit(K);`: You said that a Visitor knows how to visit anything, yet you don't show how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

On my end, the failure is the following:

```
/tmp/ccysNlSn.o: In function `Add<int>::accept(Visitor<int>)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3AddIiE6acceptE7VisitorIiE[_ZN3AddIiE6acceptE7VisitorIiE]+0x2b): undefined reference to `int Visitor<int>::visit<Add<int> >(Add<int>)'
/tmp/ccysNlSn.o:(.rodata._ZTV4ExprIiE[_ZTV4ExprIiE]+0x10): undefined reference to `Expr<int>::accept(Visitor<int>)'
/tmp/ccysNlSn.o: In function `Lit<int>::accept(Visitor<int>)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3LitIiE6acceptE7VisitorIiE[_ZN3LitIiE6acceptE7VisitorIiE]+0x2b): undefined reference to `int Visitor<int>::visit<Lit<int> >(Lit<int>)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The key errors here are the following:

```
undefined reference to `int Visitor<int>::visit<Add<int> >(Add<int>)'
undefined reference to `Expr<int>::accept(Visitor<int>)'
```

These errors mean you have not provided the implementations for `int Visitor<int>::visit<Add<int> >(Add<int>)` and `Expr<int>::accept(Visitor<int>)`. So just providing an empty implementation will fix them:

```
template<typename T>
class Visitor{
public:
    template<typename K>
    T visit(K) {};  // Added an empty body here
};

template<typename T>
class Expr{
public:
    virtual T accept(Visitor<T>) {};  // Added an empty body here
};
```

This will compile and link fine, but of course you need to supply your actual code to the implementation.